# oAuth in a regular MVC application

Tags: docusignapi

I just finished integrating DocuSign API into my C# MVC application. My MVC app is NOT .net core. So far I worked with OAuth Token Generator from the developer portal of DocuSign and hard coding the returned token.

Now I need to implement the oAuth token generation on the fly and
I need to do the Authorization Code Grant. But not sure how to implement it with C#. When I make a request to
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?XXXXXX

from MVC app I am getting a cross domain error. Please advise how to proceed?
Once again I am using a regular MVC app and NOT Core. In the sample app is in Core and
that doesn't help me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using latest Chrome? its default mode would have strict cookies and not allow an app launched from localhost to store cookies in other domains.
Another option is that you're using an iframe, that is not allowed for auth either.
I would suggest you install the [VS Extension and add DocuSign](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension) to your app as a way of a shortcut.
Otherwise, may need to debug the issue, try a different browser, host your code somewhere or change the way you do auth.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome. I need some basic help on this. How does it help installing the 'VS Extension and Add DocuSign" I don't understand.. What are my other options doing the auth?

Comment: 2 main options are Auth Code Grant and JWT. Both would require that user logs in at least once. But with JWT, you can log in once. I think the error you get is related to that part. Can you make post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: This part is on hold and I was asked do something else. Thanks for your help!